# SQL Loop not adding all input records to temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query which was written by another individual, which is having some issues. Also, I apologize for the physical length of this code lol. I realize it is long but I think it's necessary to include all the zip codes so I can present the issue I am having in it's entirety.

The query accepts a list of zip codes, loops to place them all into a table variable, and then queries that table against our database.

The issue I am having, is that it is only looping and picking up the first 31 zip codes entered. In the xample below, I have entered 89 zip codes, but the temp table, when printed, only shows 31 records.

```
--this is your list of zip codes, place a comman after every zip
SET @zip_list = 
'
30004,
31061,
30606,
27103,
28405,
53140,
60124,
60002,
44114,
77380,
75240,
77380,
75605,
72223,
72223,
76006,
78759,
76006,
50266,
50266,
50266,
49024,
78258,
67202,
92101,
92101,
92101,
92101,
90025,
90025,
55447,
90025,
92101,
90025,
55802,
55431,
55431,
55431,
37027,
02842,
10152,
10152,
02108,
07701,
08822,
94596,
94595,
55431,
92130,
92130,
95814,
95814,
93720,
95403,
94608,
92101,
19103,
08648,
18901,
18901,
18901,
19103,
85258,
85258,
85718,
85258,
85258,
98104,
98104,
97201,
89144,
92130,
92101,
92101,
97201,
97201,
97201,
63017,
63131,
22102,
21030,
22102,
22102,
20015,
22102,
20015,
20015,
20005,
06897,
' --this is your list of zip codes, place a , after every zip. Make sure the list is horizontal
---------------------------------

SET @zip_list = REPLACE(REPLACE(@zip_list,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')  --Remove new line character to place zip codes all onto one line
print @zip_list

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) > 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @tbl_zip_list
       --insert into @tbl_zip_list a substring equal to the first character from your string of zip codes + all the characters up to the first comma
       SELECT SUBSTRING(@zip_list, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) - 1) 
       --set the string of zip codes equal to your original string less the first zip code, which we just added to @tbl_zip_list
       SET @zip_list = SUBSTRING(@zip_list, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) + 1, LEN(@zip_list))
    END
----------------------------------
SELECT *
FROM @tbl_zip_list

SELECT oad.POSTAL_CODE_1,
      o.CHANNEL
FROM dbo.OFFICE AS o
    INNER JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ALIAS AS oa
    ON o.OFFICE_ID = oa.OFFICE_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ADDRESS AS oad
    ON o.ADDRESS_1_ID = oad.OFFICE_ADDRESS_ID
WHERE oa.TRADE_FIRM = @trade_firm
  AND o.CHANNEL != (SELECT f.channel
                    FROM dbo.FIRM AS f
                        INNER JOIN dbo.FIRM_ALIAS AS fa
                        ON f.FIRM_ID = fa.FIRM_ID
                    WHERE fa.trade_firm = @trade_firm)--will return the channel of the main firm */
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM @tbl_zip_list AS n1
                    WHERE n1.zip_list = oad.POSTAL_CODE_1) --this returns table of zip codes
------------------------------------------------
select f.channel as The_Default_Channel_For_Your_Firm_Is
from dbo.FIRM f INNER JOIN dbo.FIRM_ALIAS fa on f.FIRM_ID = fa.FIRM_ID
where fa.trade_firm = @trade_firm
```

I am not sure what I can do to fix the loop, so that it places all 89 zip codes into the table. Below is a screenshot of the SQL-Server output of the table. I just don't get why it's only 31 records long, when it should be 89.

[image]

Comment: Show us your `DECLARE @ZIP_LIST` -- how big is the variable?  I'm betting its too tiny.

Comment: What is `@zip_list` declared as?

Comment: Works here on MS SQL Server 2014. Which server are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys. It was the table variable length, and I should have seem That. It's One of those days. I realize it's a simple question, sorry if it offended someone enough to downvote.

Comment: Instead of a loop I would suggest taking a look at this article which explains how to split a string using a set based method instead of loop.s http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Lol Thanks Sean, I will look into it. I think you also commented on the first post I made a few days ago, when I was trying to get this query working the first time. The only issue is that I don't have write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, I get 89 back.

You must be declaring @zip_list too small to hold the entire string.

```
declare @tbl_zip_list table(zip varchar(10))
declare @zip_list varchar(8000)

--this is your list of zip codes, place a comman after every zip
SET @zip_list = 
'
30004,
31061,
30606,
27103,
28405,
53140,
60124,
60002,
44114,
77380,
75240,
77380,
75605,
72223,
72223,
76006,
78759,
76006,
50266,
50266,
50266,
49024,
78258,
67202,
92101,
92101,
92101,
92101,
90025,
90025,
55447,
90025,
92101,
90025,
55802,
55431,
55431,
55431,
37027,
02842,
10152,
10152,
02108,
07701,
08822,
94596,
94595,
55431,
92130,
92130,
95814,
95814,
93720,
95403,
94608,
92101,
19103,
08648,
18901,
18901,
18901,
19103,
85258,
85258,
85718,
85258,
85258,
98104,
98104,
97201,
89144,
92130,
92101,
92101,
97201,
97201,
97201,
63017,
63131,
22102,
21030,
22102,
22102,
20015,
22102,
20015,
20015,
20005,
06897,
' --this is your list of zip codes, place a , after every zip. Make sure the list is horizontal
---------------------------------

SET @zip_list = REPLACE(REPLACE(@zip_list,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')  --Remove new line character to place zip codes all onto one line
print @zip_list

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) > 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @tbl_zip_list
       --insert into @tbl_zip_list a substring equal to the first character from your string of zip codes + all the characters up to the first comma
       SELECT SUBSTRING(@zip_list, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) - 1) 
       --set the string of zip codes equal to your original string less the first zip code, which we just added to @tbl_zip_list
       SET @zip_list = SUBSTRING(@zip_list, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) + 1, LEN(@zip_list))
    END
----------------------------------
SELECT *
FROM @tbl_zip_list
```

Comment: I had the same results, works on my machine!  I declared @zip_list as a varchar(max) (functionally equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

The other issue COULD be if there really just aren't matching zip codes in dbo.OFFICE_ADDRESS.  To validate, run the following and see how many results you get (if you only get 31, then you know it is because there just aren't matching zip codes to those in your list).  Otherwise, it is likely what JiggsJedi said and the variable is being as too short a string

Test Query:

```
DECLARE @zip_list AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @tbl_zip_list TABLE (zip INT)
SET @zip_list = 
'
30004,
31061,
30606,
27103,
28405,
53140,
60124,
60002,
44114,
77380,
75240,
77380,
75605,
72223,
72223,
76006,
78759,
76006,
50266,
50266,
50266,
49024,
78258,
67202,
92101,
92101,
92101,
92101,
90025,
90025,
55447,
90025,
92101,
90025,
55802,
55431,
55431,
55431,
37027,
02842,
10152,
10152,
02108,
07701,
08822,
94596,
94595,
55431,
92130,
92130,
95814,
95814,
93720,
95403,
94608,
92101,
19103,
08648,
18901,
18901,
18901,
19103,
85258,
85258,
85718,
85258,
85258,
98104,
98104,
97201,
89144,
92130,
92101,
92101,
97201,
97201,
97201,
63017,
63131,
22102,
21030,
22102,
22102,
20015,
22102,
20015,
20015,
20005,
06897,
' --this is your list of zip codes, place a , after every zip. Make sure the list is horizontal
---------------------------------

SET @zip_list = REPLACE(REPLACE(@zip_list,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')  --Remove new line character to place zip codes all onto one line
print @zip_list

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) > 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @tbl_zip_list
       --insert into @tbl_zip_list a substring equal to the first character from your string of zip codes + all the characters up to the first comma
       SELECT SUBSTRING(@zip_list, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) - 1) 
       --set the string of zip codes equal to your original string less the first zip code, which we just added to @tbl_zip_list
       SET @zip_list = SUBSTRING(@zip_list, CHARINDEX(',', @zip_list) + 1, LEN(@zip_list))
    END
----------------------------------
SELECT DISTINCT zip.zip
FROM @tbl_zip_list zip
    JOIN dbo.OFFICE_ADDRESS AS oad ON zip.zip_list = oad.POSTAL_CODE_1
```